# SharePoint sites datetime settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, regional-settings

The issue is linked to SharePoint lists and DATETIME fields in those lists. Sometimes user cannot save datetime field as SharePoint throws error message requesting for it to be recorded in US format YYYY/MM/DD but the calendar picker is always in users locale format, most likely DD.MM.YYYY. Even if I try to write manualy date in whatever possible format, the record still does not want to save. Only workaround is to edit list in grid view, copy pre-existing record's date field and change it after copy pasting.
[image: Datetime Error]

Comment: Can you do the following test : try the same thing with another user in another machine and let me know the results

Comment: I bet the problem reside in the confusion between the local regional settings/the browser regional settings/SharePoint regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

The whole problem was a list setting hidden under "Advanced Settings -> **Offline Client Availability**", which as far as I can tell, somehow caches or syncs

1. On the list, click List Settings > Advanced Settings.
2. In the Offline Client Availability section, select 'No'.

Cordially.